# MySQL - Delete item from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete an item `items` table. And also from `saves` table if it exists.

This is the error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'i LEFT JOIN saves s ON i.id = s.item_id`

```
DELETE FROM items i
LEFT JOIN saves s
ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE i.id = ? AND s.item_id = ?
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)
```

Comment: you want to delete the row in saves, or just set s.item_id to NULL?

Comment: I want to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to delete from a single table, say `items` try this::**

```
DELETE i FROM items i
LEFT JOIN saves s
ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE i.id = ? AND s.item_id = ?
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)
```

**If you want to delete record from both the tables, try this::**

```
DELETE i, s FROM items i
LEFT JOIN saves s
ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE i.id = ? AND s.item_id = ?
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)
```

Comment: Quick question. If the item wasn't found in saves, would it still delete?

Comment: @ciprian Yes, since you have used the `Left Join`. If you need only the common records to be deleted, use `Inner Join`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE i, s 
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN saves s
ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE s.item_id = ?
AND
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
AND
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to delete the data from table i:

```
DELETE i FROM items i
LEFT JOIN saves s
ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE i.id = ? AND s.item_id = ?
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `i` before the `FROM` in your query

```
DELETE i FROM items i
LEFT JOIN saves s
ON i.id = s.item_id
WHERE i.id = ? AND s.item_id = ?
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM pending_wins WHERE item_id = ?)
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM bids WHERE item_id = ?)
```